# Regex.Replace c# Removing reserved characters

Tags: regex

End of the day brain overload...
I'm trying to strip out some characters that are reserved, and my escapes don't seem to be right.

`["word"]` needs to be `word`

This is what I'm attempting to use to strip `[`, `]`, `"` yet it's not working right...

```
Regex.Replace (s, "[\"\\[\\]]", "");
```

Comment: I'm wondering if it's intentional or because of markdown but try to escape it twice: `"[\"\\[\\]]"`

Comment: That was it, thank you. I suppose I should have noticed, but after doing this all day...

Comment: For a more clear question, wrap your regex in `backticks` (slanty-apostrophe next to 1 key, like \`this\`. With this, you can enter your regex just as intended. It's not clear whether you escaped slashes in post-creation and your intent is to output a single forward slash or two. I see that you've resolved the problem with HamZa's help, but good for future reference. (Code blocks should be indented four spaces, backticks works best for inline stuff)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex works just fine.

Make sure you assign the result:

```
string result = Regex.Replace (s, "[\"\\[\\]]", "");
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/c0HllP)</kbd>

---

Do consider, that you're stripping all `"`, `[` and `]` from the text. If you want to match the subject in a more strict way, you could use something similar to:

```
string result = Regex.Replace (s, "\\[\"(.*?)\"\\]", "$1");
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/TRSH0Q)</kbd>

The regex matches:

- `\\[\"` Literal `["`
- `(.*?)` Any text, repeated as few times as possible, captured in group 1 (because of the parentheses)
- `\"\\]` Literal `"]`

And replaces the match with:

- `$1` Backreference to the text captured by group 1

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
string str = @"[""word""]";

string newStr = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^a-zA-Z_0-9]", "");

Console.WriteLine(newStr); // word
```